# Upgrading Sitecore CMS 6.2 rev 100507 to Sitecore CMS 6.4.1 rev.110720 (Update-3)

Tags: module, upgrade, sitecore

I have to estimate the time we need to upgrade one of our customers Sitecore CMS from CMS 6.2 rev 100507 to CMS 6.4.1 rev.110720 (Update-3). From what I can find on the Sitecore Developer Network I can update by just getting the latest update I need and install it.
This is:

- Sitecore CMS 6.4.1 Update rev.110720 (6.4.1 Update-3)

In this Sitecore environment we also run Webforms for Marketeers  and the E-mail Campaign Manager.

- Webforms: Module: Web Forms for Marketers  Module Version: 1.0.1 rev.
  090601
- ECM: Module: E-Mail Campaign Manager Module Version: 1.0.0 rev.
  100608

If we install update rev.110720 (6.4.1 Update-3) do we also have to upgrade the modules to newer versions? What will you advise me to say about the estimated time needed to install the updates? I will try to update the Sitecore environment on my local filesystem with local databases first before installing this in the production environment (time doubles in my opinion).

Could I have some advise here, cause this will be my first big update operation.

EDIT: Please note my question above: 
Do we also have to upgrade other modules? I think we will run into a snowball effect like situation.

Comment: You can't jump straight from 6.2 -> 6.4.1, you'll have to make several upgrade steps in between to jump the major versions (typically 6.2.x -> 6.3 -> 6.4 -> 6.4.1). Find the version you want and *carefully* read the upgrade instructions, it will state that what version you require to be on before installing that upgrade, and then you need to work backwards from there until you find an upgrade that you can install on your current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try the whole process locally then double the estimate for production. Plan plan plan! I wrote a blog post a while back about planning the jumps between Sitecore versions:

http://firebreaksice.com/sitecore-upgrade-strategy/

Comment: Hey Mark, thank you for your input. I guess I also have to estimate the time needed to execute this steps locally, but I'm affraid it will be just trying out.

Comment: I'm really glad it helped. If you have any feedback on the blog post let me know as I can update it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd recommend update to 6.4.1 Update-**5**

You'll have to update WFFM and ECM modules, the other ones (you haven't specified exact list) probably don't need to be updated.

Regarding the estimates - if you're rather experienced developer, it will take ~2 days to create the update plan, get the packages / prepare configs, install the updates locally.
Plus 1 day to install all the stuff at the production server.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, this gave me a rough estimate of in what time frame I will have to think. I was heading for a rough estimation of 5 days but wanted to build in one day extra for safety. I am a rather experienced developer but this is still my first estimation for an update of this size. +1